# CUDA *.cpp files

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Is there a flag I can pass nvcc to treat a .cpp file like it would a .cu file? I would rather not have to do a `cp x.cpp x.cu; nvcc x.cu; rm x.cu`.

I ask because I have cpp files in my library that I would like to compile with/without CUDA based on particular flags  passed to the Makefile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, referring to the [nvcc documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#file-and-path-specifications) the flag is `-x`:

```
nvcc -x cu test.cpp
```

will compile `test.cpp` as if it were a `test.cu` file (i.e. pass it through the CUDA toolchain)